# linux grep with perl regex greedy not work

Tags: regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

my perl version on linux server is :

> This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

I have a test as below.

```
echo "mac:abcdefg1234" | grep -Po "(?<=mac:).*(?=\d+)"
```

The result is `abcdefg123`.

But the greedy match does not work.The result I want is `abcdefg`.
How can I get the content between "mac:" and "digital" (as many as is allowed)

Comment: `(?<=mac:)[^\d]*(?=\d+)` thats the content beetween

Comment: Hi bro,its result is ok.But why do you use [^\d]*?What is your meaning?

Comment: please explain a little more. you mean `(?<=mac:)([^\d]*)(?=\d+)` ? then you get the digits inside first variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?<=mac:)[^\d]*(?=\d+)` thats the content beetween.

`[^\d]*` means all not digital with length >=0. Typing a `^` after `[` negates the character class. The result is that the character class matches any character that is not in the character class. It also match (invisible) line break characters.

Comment: how can i rework (?=\d+) in order to catch all the digital?

Comment: It seems that it is impossible to catch all the digital but only single digital even though I use \d+ (it should be greedy).

Comment: @focuszheng please explain a little more. you mean (?<=mac:)([^\d]*)(?=\d+) ? then you get the digits inside first variable

Comment: Nope.I meant the result of (?<=mac:).*(?=\d+) includes digital "123".I want to know why this happened.Your answer work for me.

Comment: so may check my answer please?

Comment: sure,I have checked.

Comment: @focuszheng please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and try again

Comment: echo "mac:abcdefg1234" | grep -Po "(?<=mac:).*?(?=\d\d)" It works as well.